# MongoDB with python bulk operations insert update

Tags: python, mongodb, batch-insert

Is it possible to have a bulk operation in MongoDB (with python) where insert and update commands are mixed? Updated records can be the ones that would be inserted in the same batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. PyMongo 2.7 added a "Bulk API" which you can read about [here.](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html#mixed-bulk-write-operations) PyMongo 3.0 is adding an alternative API to do the same thing that is very similar to what you mention in a comment to another answer. See [this commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/commit/be0ad8dec3687700edb2ed8363eb99257ba5ccd3) for a preview.

Comment: The outdated mymongo was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super clear on what you're asking but mongo supports "upsert" which allow for inserting if record does not exist:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#definition

> upsert Optional. If set to true, creates a new document when no
>   document matches the query criteria. The default value is false, which
>   does not insert a new document when no match is found.

Comment: What i mean is a list of update/insert commands, such like

` [insert({record details}), update({record details})]`